# How can I print numbers in python with thin space characters as the thousands separators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, output

I know for example  "{:,}".format(123456789) will print '123,456,789' as output in python.

However, instead of the commas I would like the thin space character as the thousands separator. According to [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm), the python source encoding for the thin space character is u"\u2009".

So I tried replacing the comma in "{:,}" by u"\u2009", but that results in a syntax error. This might be because python can't deal with the resulting nested double quotes and something needs to be escaped.

So is there a way to make this, or some other mechanism work? And by the way I'd like to suppress the single quotes that appear in the output as well.

Comment: It would help to show an example and the exact error. `"{:\u2009}".format(123456789)` gives a different error: `ValueError: Unknown format code '\x2009' for object of type 'int'` but at least its not a syntax error!

Comment: As per https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language you can have only `_` or `,` as grouping option. So, you should use string replace as mentioned in the answers below.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `replace` method from `str` to replace `,` by thin spaces after having formatted it, i.e: `"{:,}".format(123456789).replace(",", u"\u2009")`

According to the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-type), only `,` and `_` can be used as separators. To use a user-defined one, you need to use the `n` representation, and change your `locale` settings (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.LC_NUMERIC). You can create a new localization and use this fake localization for what you want but this is a rather complicated solution.

EDIT: By a fake localization, I really mean a new locale in your computer, not in Python. You can read https://askubuntu.com/questions/653008/how-to-create-a-new-system-locale for more details (I think this can be adapterd on most distributions)

Answer (score 3):

I can offer you an obvious workaround:

```
>>> n = 123456789
>>> print(f'{n:,}'.replace(',', u'\u2009'))
123 456 789
```

Works for `str.format` the same way.

Comment: I tried you solution a long time ago in both python and ipython, but in both cases the thousands separator turned out to be the space rather than the thin space. I'm puzzled as to how you got a thin space, since on my Mac's python at least, the thin space is rendered as a space.

Comment: @redwood_gm Beware that Jupyter notebooks uses a monospaced font by default, in which there is no visual distinction between thin and standard spaces.  That does not mean the workaround didn’t work (you can obviously check by assigning to a variable instead of printing).

Comment: What Skippy said also applies to most terminal emulators, since they rely on fixed width (monospaced) fonts to display properly. Try changing to a non-monospaced font and see how happy you are with it (you will be very unhappy with it).